# Azure node.js iisnode_shema.xml The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: node.js, azure

I'm using the latest Windows Azure SDK for Node.js (August 2012) from Web Platform Installer. When I try to run my node application I get this error in the log file:

G:\node\mathwizard\local_package.csx\roles\WebRole2\approot\bin>copy /y "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell\x64\iisnode_schema.xml" "C:\Program Files\IIS Express\config\schema\iisnode_schema.xml" 
The system cannot find the path specified.

Cannot connect to the application in the browser.

Any help please?

Comment: are you running in the emulator (i.e., start-AzureEmulator -launch) or are you pulling this log file from a VM instance in Azure?

Comment: Running in the Emulator.

Comment: not quite sure what's going on.. it's working here (start-AzureEmulator -launch) and I don't have that source file either or even the x64 directory for that matter. I do have the file in the config/schema directory however.  So if you start from scratch (new-AzureServiceProject, add-AzureNodeWebRole, start-AzureEmulator -launch) you'll see that same error?

Comment: That worked. Created a new node app and works 100%. Went to my original app, run the command Add-AzureNodeWebRole and everything worked again. Don't know what is going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We made some changes between the July and August releases that make it necessary to migrate your project over to the new August format if you want to use the August tools. As you discovered, if you recreate the project, copy over all your node files unchanged, it should just work. Sorry for the inconvenience!

We have filed this issue https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools/issues/331 to investigate further.